# Cannot find X.509 certificate using FindByThumbprint

Tags: .net, x509

I am getting the following error when I try to instantiate an instance of a third party web service client...

```
Cannot find the X.509 certificate using the following search criteria:
StoreName 'My', StoreLocation 'LocalMachine', FindType 'FindByThumbprint', 
FindValue '[value in here]'.
```

The strange thing is that we have this working on another development machine, but it is steadfastly refusing to work on mine. We have added the certificate to the machine's certificate store in the same way (as far as we can tell) on each machine.

Can anyone offer any suggestions about how to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you don't have the certificate installed on that machine. Take a look on Internet Explorer (Tools | Internet Options | Content tab | Certificates) installed client certificates.

Under "Personal" tab you can see the installed certificates for you user account (as you are using the "My" store name). Double-clicking on an installed certificate under Details tab you have all information you can use on find value attribute, like the thumbprint.

Note that on Windows 10, the certificates are found in the local "Computer" store. On Windows Server 2008 R2 and below, they will be found in "Personal".

Comment: What do you do if the certificate is actually installed. FindByThumbprint is not working for me, but if I use FindBySubjectName, it does. Any thoughts?

Comment: I just found the answer to my problem and wanted to post in case someone came across this.  The problem was there were some unicode control chars in the FindValue string that didn't show in Visual Studio. When I used a HEX editor, I saw these chars. I removed them, and then I was able to find the cert.

Comment: Another note... the thumbprint should not have any spaces in it. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734695.aspx

Comment: Right-click the file, click open with, Binary Editor and see if there's a few extra bytes in that string... @.@ +1 for you Bryan :)

Comment: Ran into a similar problem with WcfTestClient in VS2019 on Windows 10 Pro. Certificates mentioned above need to be placed in local "Computer" store, not "Personal". Windows Server 2008 R2 and below still use "Personal".

Answer (score 1):

Here's what worked for me:

**Invalid** - `252967BFBCD543D93A79AFD86D4A5117A9C6767B`

Added `0x` (prefix for hexadecimal numeric constants)

**Valid** - `0x252967BFBCD543D93A79AFD86D4A5117A9C6767B`